# Unable to Deploy Django Project On Gcloud

Tags: python, django, firebase, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I'm want to deploy my Django project with MySQL on Gcloud I have done all configurations
but I'm getting a major issue and it cant be deployed

**Im getting this error**

> "ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: This deployment has too
> many files. New versions are limited to 10000 files for this app. -
> '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest   fieldViolations:
>
> - description: This deployment has too many files. New versions are limited to 10000       files for this app.     field:
>   version.deployment.files[...]  django"

App.yaml

```
# [START django_app]
runtime: python38
handlers:
# This configures Google App Engine to serve the files in the app's
# static directory.
- url: /static
  static_dir: static/
# This handler routes all requests not caught above to the main app. 
# It is required when static routes are defined, but can be omitted 
# (along with the entire handlers section) when there are no static 
# files defined.
- url: /.*
  script: auto
# [END django_app]
```

**I dont have idea why im getting this error so please let me know so I can fix this issue**
also this is view for sql data
[Sql Statics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfvSy.png)

**Please guys help me to fix this issue**

Comment: You're trying to upload too many files. It's possible you're including some directories that aren't necessary for deployment. Can you include your `.gcloudignore` and `.gitignore` (if you have one)? Can you tell us what your application's directory structure looks like?

Comment: is your `virtualenv` within of your project folder? if this the case add your virtualenv folder in `.gcloudignore` file, or move the virtualenv to another folder.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you're including some directories or files that aren't necessary for deployment, for example the `virtualenv`.

You can avoid the upload of these folders and files in the files, by creating the file`.gcloudignore`, within this file you can specified which files will be ignored to be uploaded to App Engine

For more information about the syntax of `gcloudignore` check this [document](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/gcloudignore)